# Is there a consensus in economics about public housing?

Tags: public-economics, government, government-spending

I'm looking for a meta - analysis / review discussing the question if public housing has a net benefit to the public.

EDIT: To be more specific I follow the definition used in the United States where public housing is classified either as housing projects that are owned by a city's Housing authority or federally subsidized public housing operated through a federal authority.

Comment: what exact public housing scheme you are interested in? There is extremely large heterogeneity in how public housing is executed in different countries. Unless you are bit more specific what type of policy called public housing you are interested in this is too broad

Comment: @1muflon1 Added a definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a couple on the internet which I didn't read. If you think they're of no use, let me know and I'll take down the answer.

1. [Does public housing reduce housing cost burden among low-income families with children?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7331941/)
2. [The Benefits and Costs of the Section 8 Housing Subsidy Program: A Framework and First-Year Estimates](https://www.irp.wisc.edu/publications/dps/pdfs/dp138010.pdf)
3. [Assessing the Economic Benefits of Public Housing](https://clpha.org/sites/default/files/documents/EconsultFinalReport2007_2.pdf)
4. [THE ECONOMIC IMPACT OF PUBLIC HOUSING](https://clpha.org/sites/default/files/documents/EconomicImpactPublicHousing_final2_digital_0.pdf)
5. [Estimating the Benefits of Public-Housing Programs: A Characteristics Approach](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229931147_Estimating_the_Benefits_of_Public-Housing_Programs_A_Characteristics_Approach)

Comment: Thanks for you effort. I will read into them. If nobody answers the bounty goes to you.